# Does a delay effect with a Send parameter exist?

Tags: delay

On the Nord Electro 4 keyboard, the delay effect parameter is a "Send" parameter: it controls how much of the signal goes into the delay, just like a send on a mixer.

I'd like to find a delay pedal with the same parameter. Most of the delay pedals have controls for the time, the feedback and the delay volume (+ other parameters for modulation for example), but I've never found one with a send parameter. Does any pedal with such a parameter exist?

I know it can be done with a mixer but I'd like to keep my setup simple.

Comment: Just look for one with a 'mix' control; there are many. Semi-random link - https://www.musicradar.com/news/the-10-best-delay-pedals-our-pick-of-the-best-effects-for-guitar

Comment: @Tetsujin I would normally think of a mix control as being at position '4' in my picture, more like a 'return'. That's no fun if you want to play dry over some feeding-back thing that you played already; you need a variable 'send' for that.

Comment: Your best bet is probably going to be a multi-fx pedal where you can assign the expression pedal to different parameters.

Answer (score 1):

I started [a thread on another site about something similar](https://www.thegearpage.net/board/index.php?threads/delay-pedals-where-you-can-control-the-send-level-via-expression.1597555/).

[image: Send points]

Basically, I wanted a control point at '1', so that I could change the amount of delay effect being applied to the notes I was playing, without changing the level of the notes already feeding back. I wanted to be able to control that with an expression pedal. As far as I can tell from a quick scan of that thread, I did find a couple of pedals that I confirmed did what I wanted: the Boss space echo, and the Neunaber series.

That was some time ago - I hope there might be more available now! I'm not sure I can think of a particular search term for pedals with this as a variable parameter, but you can get a "poor man's" version of this effect - on/off only, rather than variable send - by looking for any delay pedal with 'trails'. (it's more comfortable to control if the pedal has a soft switch).

Answer (score 0):

If you want a specific example witha  delay that can be mixed in without the use of a mixer, Electro-Harmonix's Canyon delay pedal allows you to decide the intensity of the delay and how much is used via a mix knob on the pedal.